# Automatically modifying text files

Tags: perl, replace, scripting, automation, text-processing

Here is my problem: I have a directory containing a bunch of sample code from the Oracle Instant Client. Each of them demonstrates a simple database operation. My objective is to change all of their connection sequences.

There are two ways they connect. Either they do

```
EXEC SQL CONNECT :username IDENTIFIED BY :password;
```

or they do

```
EXEC SQL CONNECT :uid;
```

In the first case, earlier in the program we define variables

```
char *username = "scott";
char *password = "tiger";
```

Whenever I encounter a program using this sequence, I first want to change the password and then I want to add a line below the two above to get the following

```
char *username = "scott";
char *password = "newPassword";
char *sqlHost = "hostid";
```

Then I will need to change the connection sequence above (we are in case 1) to

```
EXEC SQL CONNECT :username IDENTIFIED BY :password USING :sqlHost;
```

If we are in case two, then earlier in the program we define the variable

```
char *uid = "scott/tiger";
```

This case is easier to handle: all I need to do is change the definition to

```
char *uid = "scott/newPassword/hostid";
```

and I can leave the connection sequence untouched.

I'm not asking for someone to write this whole thing for me, just to give me some pointers. I have been reading some Perl documentation to get ideas, but I am not sure how to dynamically change the file cursor so I can insert a line directly after a matched pattern. I am also not totally sure how I can have a single script differentiate between the two cases (then again, maybe I won't have to, assuming I can write my patterns to only ever match on one or the other.)

Another way I could solve this is to change all of them to connect using the second type of sequence. In this case I suppose I could just insert a new line declaring a `uid` as I want and then modifying the connection sequence to always take the form of the second type. I would also want to remove the previous variable declarations of `username` and `password`.

Thanks SO.

Answer (score 0):

For files that fit into memory:

1. 'slurp' the file into an array
2. loop through the lines of the array

   - check each line for a match to $usernameRe, saving the line number if there's a match
   - check each line for a match to $prefixRe

     - if the line matches to $caseOnePrefixRe, note the line number & flag it as Case 1
     - else flag it as Case 2
     - terminate the loop
3. use the saved array indexes to update the (existing) lines as required
4. loop through the array to write the lines to output

   - adding the appropriate extra line, if needed, based on the saved array index

For files which won't fit into memory, you'll have to make 2 passes through each file, processing a line at a time.

Simple regular expressions are sufficient in this case:

```
use strict ;
use warnings ;
use Test::More ;

my $usernameStr = 'char *username = "scott"' ;
my $usernameRe = qr/char\s\*username\s=/ ;
like( $usernameStr, $usernameRe, "username RE works" ) ;

my $caseOneStr = 'EXEC SQL CONNECT :username IDENTIFIED BY :password;' ;
my $caseTwoStr = 'EXEC SQL CONNECT :uid;' ;
my $prefixRe = qr/EXEC\sSQL\sCONNECT\s/ ;
like( $caseOneStr, $prefixRe, "Prefix RE works for Case 1" ) ;   
like( $caseTwoStr, $prefixRe, "Prefix RE works for Case 2" ) ;

my $caseOnePrefixRe =  qr/EXEC\sSQL\sCONNECT\s:[[:alnum:]]+\sIDENTIFIED\sBY/ ;
like ( $caseOneStr, $caseOnePrefixRe, "Case 1 prefix RE works for Case 1" ) ;    
unlike ( $caseTwoStr, $caseOnePrefixRe, "Case 1 prefix RE rejects Case 2" ) ;
```

If the files can be held in memory, then do something like this to read a file into an array of lines:

```
my $filename = 'foo' ;
open my $fh, "<", $filename ;
my @lines = <$fh> ;
close $fh ;
```

Use an indexed 'for' to loop through the array of lines:

```
for ( my $i = 0; $i < scalar( @lines ); $i++ ) {
    # scan &/or update $lines[$i] in this iteration
}
```

For more on 'slurping' files, see [Perl Slurp Ease](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Slurp/extras/slurp_article.pod).

For more on 'like()' and 'unlike()', see [Test::More](http://p3rl.org/Test%3a%3aMore).